# Definition of the field trace

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_trace), there is a definition of field trace

> Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension. For $\alpha\in L$, let $\sigma_1(\alpha),...,\sigma_{n}(\alpha)$ be the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ (in some extension field of $K$). Then
> $$\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha) = [L:K(\alpha)]\sum_{j=1}^n\sigma_j(\alpha)$$

The question is that

> $\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha) = \operatorname{Tr}(m_\alpha)$ where $m_\alpha:L\to L$ is a linear transformation given by $x\mapsto \alpha x$ (considering $L$ as a vector space over $K$)

I already learned some undergraduate level linear algebra and field theory. But I didn't learn such stuff. How can I prove this?

Comment: @MorganRodgers I mean $\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha)$ is defined as a trace of a linear transformation. I wonder why LHS and RHS are the same.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Changed the question. Thank you for your comment

Comment: @MorganRodgers I think it's safe to mention just $m_\alpha$ is linear transformation because base doesn't matter for trace.

Comment: @PeterJohn The choice of basis matters when trying to calculate the trace. Some bases make it a lot easier than others. And in particular, picking a basis may make it a lot easier to calculate than trying to do it abstractly and coordinate-free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick elements $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_k\in L$ such that the monomials $\alpha^i\beta_1^{j_1}\beta_2^{j_2}\ldots\beta_k^{j_k}$ for suitable exponents (with $0\leq i<n$) make a basis of $L$ over $K$. Let's order them lexicographically according to $(j_1,j_2,\ldots,j_k,i)$.

In this basis, the matrix representation of $m_\alpha$ has mostly zeroes on the diagonal (and ones on the subdiagonal), except from every $n$th entry where it has the negative of the $(n-1)$th degree coefficient of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. This entry is equal to the sum of the roots of that minimal polynomial by Vieta's relations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You argue for the case $L =K(\alpha,\beta)$ for simplicity right? In general we would have $K(\alpha,\beta_1,...,\beta_m)$ for some $m$.

Comment: @PeterJohn I think it's fixed now. Yes, that was for simplicity. I think it's still pretty clear now, though.